# Postgres “missing FROM-clause entry” error on distinct select query

Tags: postgresql, datatable, inner-join, distinct

Below error is generated while creating a inner join on 2 tables in PostgreSQL with distinct clause.Here is my query :

```
select distinct public."firstapp_offer_Vendor".user_id from 
(SELECT 
    public.firstapp_bid.id,
    public.firstapp_bid."Bid",
    public.firstapp_bid.offer_id,
    public."firstapp_offer_Vendor".user_id,
    public."firstapp_offer_Vendor".offer_id
FROM
    public.firstapp_bid
inner JOIN public."firstapp_offer_Vendor"
    ON public."firstapp_offer_Vendor".offer_id = public.firstapp_bid.offer_id)  as foo;
```

but as i execute it,this error is generated.Please help.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 11: ...r".offer_id = public.firstapp_bid.offer_id) public."firstapp...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select distinct user_id from 
(SELECT 
    fb.id,
    fb.Bid,
    fb.offer_id,
    fov.user_id,
    fov.offer_id
FROM
    public.firstapp_bid as fb
inner JOIN public.firstapp_offer_Vendor as fov
    ON fov.offer_id = fb.offer_id)  as foo;
```